# Change ImageView Size Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, swift, uiimageview

I have a problem changing an `UIImageView`'s size. The thing is that I want to make an Universal App and I just can't make the `UIImageView` to get bigger when the detected device is an iPad.

Right now I'm using this code:

```
 if (UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Phone)
 {
     self.image.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
 }
 else if (UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Pad)
 {
     self.image.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
     self.image.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024)
 }
```

The thing is, it does changes the color but it doesn't change the image size. So how can I manage to change the size? And I don't want to use auto layout, I want to use code. Thanks!

Comment: is the image created in xib/storyboard file?

Comment: Yes it is in the Storyboard file.

Comment: is the storyboard using autolayout? is it checked? if so, you can add the autolayout code to your file by adding constraints. If not, you will have to use the old string and struts method.

Comment: No, the autolayout isn't checked. Which is the old string and struts method?

Comment: answer below.. however, since you are using swift, there is no reason not to use autolayout, i would recommend using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in objective-c its like this

```
 [imageView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
```

OR

in interface builder, click the arrows so it looks like this

[image]

You can lookup the swift syntax! hope this works